# merging and joining the wo pandas data frames with out including right side data frame columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes like given below.

```
***df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 'b':[1,2,1,2,1,2], 'c':[1,2,4,0,0,2]})***
```

df1

```
a   b   c
```

0   1   1   1
1   1   2   2
2   2   1   4
3   2   2   0
4   3   1   0
5   3   2   2

```
***df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2], 'b':[1,2,1,2], 'c':[1,5,6,2]})***
```

df2

```
a   b   c
```

0   1   1   1
1   1   2   5
2   2   1   6
3   2   2   2

I want to apply inner join of the both data frames and don't want the columns from df2, so tried with below code.

```
***merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=["a", "b"], right_on=["a","b"])***

a   b   c_x c_y
```

0   1   1   1   1
1   1   2   2   5
2   2   1   4   6
3   2   2   0   2

from the above code without droping c_x and c_y manually, is there any way to not to merge right dataframe(df2)
basically, I want all the columns from df1 and don't want any columns from df2 after merging.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is filter only columns for merging, here `a,b`. If want merge by both columns `on` parameter should be omit (then pandas merge by intersection of columns in both `DataFrames`):

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2[["a", "b"]])
```

working like:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2[["a", "b"]], on=['a','b'])
```

Comment: great, this worked. merged_df = df1.merge(df2[["a", "b"]], on=['a','b'])